# Convert empty dictionary to empty string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
>>> d = {}
>>> s = str(d)
>>> print s
{}
```

I need an empty string instead.

Comment: I am very curious as to why there is a 500 rep bounty on this question.

Comment: @LeoCHan: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I am very curious as to why your comment got 9 upvotes (now) also :P. Anyway, [the answer is that I want to be a 10ker](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28795645#28795645).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it with the shortest way as below, since the empty dictionary is `False`, and do it through [Boolean Operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

```
>>> d = {}
>>> str(d or '')
''
```

Or without `str`

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d or ''
''
```

If `d` is not an empty dictionary, convert it to string with `str()`

```
>>> d['f'] = 12
>>> str(d or '')
"{'f': 12}"
```

Answer (score 8):

An empty dict object is `False` when you try to convert it to a bool object. But if there's something in it, it would be `True`. Like empty list, empty string, empty set, and other objects:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d
{}
>>> bool(d)
False
>>> d['foo'] = 'bar' 
>>> bool(d)
True
```

So it's simple:

```
>>> s = str(d) if d else ''
>>> s
"{'foo': 'bar'}"
>>> d = {}
>>> s = str(d) if d else ''
>>> s
''
```

Or just `if not d: s = ''` if you don't need `s` be string of the dict when there's something in the dict.

Comment: @mr_bulrathi You can click the check sign to accept this as an answer to close the question.

Comment: @Selcuk: Ah, yes and no. *accepting* not *closing* ;)

Comment: @KevinGuan "Closing" as in "not listed as unanswered anymore" :)

Comment: @Selcuk: Hey, it's not bad to answering a question which already has an accepted answer. Also we can change the accepted answer if it's better than the already accepted one. So I think, the "not listed as unanswered anymore" is incorrect in this case :P

Comment: @KevinGuan You are right, but I am simply talking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python

Comment: @Selcuk: Ah, that one. Yeah you're correct. "Remove this question from that page".

Comment: @KevinGuan here the **singe quote('')**  wont work `s = str(d) if d else ''` but when i print it is showing null space but when i tried this with `s=str(d) if d else ""` it works we have to use **double quote ""**

Comment: @JohnAnkanna: Err...`''` is *nothing*, *not a space*. And `"" == ''`. They're the same thing. However, `'' != ' '`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> #### Truth Value Testing
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while`
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - **any empty mapping, for example, `{}`**.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()`
>     or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or `bool`
>     value `False`.

So your empty dictionary turns out to be `False` according to that bolded rule. So you can use:

```
d = {}
if not d:
   s = ''
else:
   s = str(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert each item in the dictionary to a string, then join them with the empty string,

```
>>> ''.join(map(str,d))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose sub classing dict and overriding the `__str__` method:

```
class DontForgetToDoYourTaxes(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return self or ""
```

Then to use:

```
d = DontForgetToDoYourTaxes()
print d  # ""
d["ayy"] = "lmao"
print d  # "{'ayy': 'lmao'}"
```