# Scrape data from PubMed

Tags: python, web-scraping, pubmed, rentrez

I have written the following function to extract data from PubMed using Entrez:

```
def getFromPubMed(id):
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed",rettype="medline",retmode="text", id=str(id))
    records = Medline.parse(handle)
    for record in records:
        abstract = str(record["AB"])
        mesh = str(record["MH"]).replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
        pmid = str(record["PMID"])
        title = str(record["TI"]).replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
        pt = str(record["PT"]).replace("'", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
        au = str(record["AU"])
        dp = str(record["DP"])
        la = str(record["LA"])
        pmc = str(record["PMC"])
        si = str(record["SI"])
        try:
            doi=str(record["AID"])
        except:
            doi = str(record["SO"]).split('doi:',1)[1]
        return pmid, title, abstract, au, mesh, doi, pt, la, pmc
```

However, this function will not always work as not all MEDLINE records contain all fields. For example, this [PMID](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=29387250) doesn't contain any MeSH headings.

I could wrap each item with a try-except statement, for example for `abstract`:

```
try:
  abstract = str(record["AB"])
except:
  abstract = ""
```

but it seems a clunky way to implement this. Whats a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the action of extracting the fields off to a seperate method - doing something like the below:

```
def get_record_attributes(record, attr_details):
    attributes = {}

    for attr_name, details in attr_details.items():
        value = ""
        try:
            value = record[details["key"]]

            for char in details["chars_to_remove"]:
                value = value.replace(char, "")
        except KeyError, AttributeError:
            pass

        attributes[attr_name] = value

    return attributes

def getFromPubMed(id):
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed",rettype="medline",retmode="text", id=str(id))
    records = Medline.parse(handle)
    for record in records:
        attr_details = {
            "abstract" : {"key" : "AB"},
            "mesh" : { "key" : "MH", "chars_to_remove" : "'[]"},
            #...
            "aid" : {"key" : "AB"},
            "so" : {"key" : "SO"},
        }

        attributes = get_record_attributes(record, attr_details)

       #...
```

Comment: This works really well. Thanks. Note it should be `attributes[attr_name] = value` not `attribute[attr_name] = value`.

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
mesh = str(record["MH"] or '')
```

Since an empty dictionary is `FALSE` as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389648/convert-empty-dictionary-to-empty-string) suggests